# Command line 'subl' not working for Sublime Text 2

Tags: macos, terminal, sublimetext2

Tried setting up Sublime Text 2 using an alias and then a ln syslink 
Alias:

```
alias subl='/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'
```

Then Syslink

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

Both returned the error:

```
~bash: /Applications/Sublime: No such file or directory
```

So I tried going into `/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/` and running `subl` directly out of frustration and discovered that `subl` was actually returning  the error.

```
~bash: /Applications/Sublime: No such file or directory
```

The alias and syslink had worked it was `subl` that was returning the error. Any ideas of how to correct this?

Comment: when you were in `/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin` did you run `subl` or `./subl`? If you just ran `subl` then you were still using your alias, you need to run `./subl` to actually run the `subl` command in the current directory.

Comment: thanks, you were right. I was just calling the alias again.

Answer (score 2):

Your alias is set up incorrectly, and is overriding your symlink as aliases are evaluated by the shell before searching `$PATH`. Try running the following (note the double quotes and the lack of escape sequences):

```
alias subl="/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
```

If that works, you can then add it to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`, whichever you use.